# How to add external compare tool (Beyond Compare) to TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, beyondcompare

Generally I'd prefer default compare tool in VS2013 as it has better syntax highlighting, and it can locate at first diff when opening.

But sometimes I'd like to use Beyond Compare, as I can easily copy diffs between two files.

I know how to change compare tool in TFS, but we can only use one tool at a time. Is it possible to add external compare tools to context menu of TFS?